# How to create Groovy class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

My Computer is Macbook pro, the computer's system version is: OS X 10.11.4 (OS X El Capitan)

My Eclipse's version is 4.5.

the Eclipse is installed Groovy plugin (URL is http://dist.springsource.org/milestone/GRECLIPSE/e4.3/) ;

restart my Eclipse.

---

I create a Groovy project ----> success

I create a Groovy class ----> error !

have 2 alert .

the 1st :
    ‘Building workspace’ has encountered a problem . Errors occurred during the build .

```
error details : Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'GroovyJavaProject'.
org/codehaus/jdt/groovy/integration/LanguageSupportFactory
```

the 2nd :
    Creation of element failed .
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit cannot be cast to org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.model.GroovyCompilationUnit.

[image]

Comment: What details are shown if you click on the `Details` button in dialog `Problem Occured`?

Comment: Details : Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'GroovyJavaProject'.
org/codehaus/jdt/groovy/integration/LanguageSupportFactory

Comment: If you want to avoid problems change your IDE and use IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. The Groovy Support is excellent. You wont go back to Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the update site you have used is not the right one

From [Groovy/Grails Tool Suite™ Downloads](http://spring.io/tools/ggts/all) page the update link for Eclipse 4.5 is http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.5/.

I believe the one you have used is for Eclipse 4.3.